# Python can't find module, although the reasons given in other questions don't seem to apply

Tags: python-3.x, importerror

I am trying to import 'indra'. It is in my sys.path:

```
Python 3.4.1 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Sep 10 2014, 17:24:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys, pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sys.path)
['',
'/Users/gcallah/TechProjects/indra/indra',
'/Users/gcallah/TechProjects/indra/models',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python34.zip',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Sphinx-1.2.3-py3.4.egg',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/runipy-0.1.1-py3.4.egg',
'/Users/gcallah/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools-5.8-py3.4.egg']
```

It has an `__init__.py` file in the directory.

So I run this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
This is a simple test script. 
"""

import logging
import indra.prop_args as props
```

I get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'indra'
```

Comment: If you want to be able to import a package `foo`, you put the folder containing the `foo` folder on the path, not the `foo` folder itself. Is that the problem?

Comment: Please show us the structure of the files under `/Users/gcallah/TechProjects/indra/`.

Comment: Macintosh:indra gcallah$ pwd
/Users/gcallah/TechProjects/indra
Macintosh:indra gcallah$ ls
Graphics README.md docs  models
LICENSE  README.md~ indra  release.sh
Macintosh:indra gcallah$

Comment: Yes, user23 etc. that was t he problem.